# SPSS cslogistic note

Tags: logistic, spss, odds-ratio

I'm calculating odds ratios using the following model. I need to know what the last note means. I have stated the levels for odd ratios for the levels I'm interested in, so I don't know what SPSS means when certain variables are "fixed" at certain values. I haven't specified these requirements, so why are the fixed?

```
CSLOGISTIC  assault(LOW) BY unemployed4 demgroup location4 timeofday2 v4043
  /PLAN FILE='C:\Users\Ward\Documents\Incident_NCVS9212.csaplan' 
  /MODEL demgroup location4 unemployed4  timeofday2 v4043 location4*unemployed4 demgroup*location4 timeofday2*unemployed4 timeofday2*location4 v4043*unemployed4
  /INTERCEPT INCLUDE=YES SHOW=YES
  /TEST TYPE=F PADJUST=SEQBONFERRONI
 /ODDSRATIOS FACTOR=[location4] CONTROL=[unemployed4(3)]
    /MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE
  /CRITERIA MXITER=100 MXSTEP=50 PCONVERGE=[1E-006 RELATIVE] LCONVERGE=[0] CHKSEP=20 CILEVEL=95
  /PRINT SUMMARY VARIABLEINFO SAMPLEINFO.
EXECUTE.


Odds Ratios                 
        Assault Odds Ratio  95% Confidence Interval 
                Lower   Upper
Location reverse coding Outside areas vs. Home  1.00    1.755   1.544   1.996
    Parking lots vs. Home   1.00    .625    .528    .738
    Commercial areas vs. Home   1.00    1.513   1.284   1.781
    Friend's home vs. Home  1.00    2.652   2.193   3.208

Dependent Variable: Assault (reference category = .00) 
Model: (Intercept), demgroup, location4, unemployed4, timeofday2, V4043, unemployed4 * location4, demgroup * location4, unemployed4 * timeofday2, location4 * timeofday2, unemployed4 * V4043                   

***Factors and covariates used in the computation are fixed at the following values: unemployed4=Employed; Demographic group=Male single; Location reverse coding=Home; timeofday2=Daytime; HOW FAR FROM HOME=> 50 miles***
```

Answer (score 1):

You have interaction terms in the model, and you've asked for odds ratios to be reported. (You've asked SPSS to use variable labels in the output [I think] so we can't directly link output and syntax.)

Location4 interacts with several variables, so the odds ratio of location4 depends on the values of the other variables. Simple example: You can't say what the effect of wearing a seatbelt is on injuries, unless you know if you've crashed or not. You have a more complex version of seatbelt, crashed, and seatbelt*crashed in your model, with injuries as the outcome.

SPSS is saying "Sure, I can give you the odds ratios of location4, but I have to pick a value for the variables that it interacts with. These are the values I've chosen."

Comment: I get it. Thanks! To fix those variables at other values, I need to specify them in the control/factor statements? Is there another statement that might let me do that?

Comment: Not sure. I always prefer to do that 'by hand', unless I'm really, really sure what the program is doing.